# How can I change the root password using sudo over SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sudo

I am trying to reset the root password over SSH, using sudo, as directly logging in as root is disabled.

I'm using the below command to reset the password:

```
sshpass -f .pass ssh kj@server2 'bash -s' < password.sh
```

When running this I am prompted for the sudo password and it's failing.

*password.sh* has the below content.

```
MYPASS=abcd@123

echo $MYPASS | sudo -kS bash -c 'echo passwd | passwd root --stdin'
```

How can I successfully reset the password using SSH and sudo?

Comment: Why not just directly login to the server and run `sudo passwd root` interactively? Your user `kj` will have to have permission to use `sudo` and `passwd`.

Comment: if it was one server its fine but I need to do it on more then 70 servers. and yes kj have sudo permission on all the servers.

Comment: Are you able to do it manually for one server by running `sudo passwd root`? Just to verify you're actually able to do that. Right now you'd set the password to `passwd` and not `MYPASS`.

Comment: Yes, I was able to.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by running the below command:

```
sshpass -f .pass ssh kj@server2 "echo abcd@123 | sudo -kS bash -c 'echo passwd | passwd root --stdin'"
```

If there is a better solution I'd welcome your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve this by writing something like this:

```
ssh user@machine 'sudo passwd' << END
<password>
<password>
END
```

I would further like to recommend you to use certificates, rather than passwords, to log into your machines, as that would make procedures like this a bit easier

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/593940)

Comment: The question is "How can I successfully reset the password using SSH and sudo?", and this is an answer showing a way to do that. What is the proeblem?

Comment: You answer has been flagged as very low quality (not by me). You have phrased your answer in a way that asks the OP to clarify something. If you can add some additional context I am sure it will be fine. Please see [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Characters such as `` $"\` `` in `$MYPASS` maybe being expanded by bash, and so the password that is sent to sudo would not be what you expect it to be.

To print a string literally without bash expansion use `printf '%s\n' "$1"`

```
sshpass -f "$SSH_PASS" ssh -t -l "$SSH_USER" -p "$SSH_PORT" "$SERVER" \
    "printf '%s\n' \"root:$PASSWORD\" | sudo chpasswd -c SHA512"
```

Comment: there is no issue with $MYPASS. issue is I was not able to run the same using ssh.